# How to remove the linearly dependent rows of an integer matrix in a computationally efficient way?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Can somebody help how to remove the linearly dependent rows of a large ($\sim 100,000 \times 100,000$) integer matrix?

I would like to write a program for this purpose. Can I utilize the integer property of the matrix for the numerical efficiency? Thank you for the advances provided.

Comment: Why not use Gaussian elimination?

Comment: I thought about it, namely, I have a Gaussian elimination subroutine with floating point arithmetics. I have read about the integer-preserving Gaussian elimination not using divisions, but I don't know whether it is worth applying it or not. Is it possible to use somehow one of the conjugate gradient methods?

Comment: Aren't conjugate gradient methods used when the matrix is symmetric and positive definite? If your matrix has linearly dependent rows, it cannot be positive definite. I am assuming that the matrix is square.

Comment: If it would be square... Unfortunately, it is a general rectangular matrix. Is it worth using integer preserving Gaussian elimination?

Comment: You don't need to preserve integrality. The goal is to find the number of pivots (i.e., the rank) and remove redundant rows.

Comment: Try Gauss in modular arithmetic with several relatively small primes. This should give the dependent rows with high probability.

Comment: I wish I knew what meant it... May you explain it, LutzL, please?